# Download of Ubuntu 22.04 returns 0 byte .iso file

Tags: iso, downloads

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu 22.04 USB installation drive. But the downloaded .iso file shows a size of 0 Bytes. The steps I followed to download the .iso file are given below;

1. I accessed the official Ubuntu website for downloading the .iso file: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04.1&architecture=amd64#download
2. The downloaded file is present in my download directory:
   /home/lloyd/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64(2).iso, but the size is displayed as 0 bytes.

Why is this happening ? And how can I download correct files to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check if your browser is still downloading the file to some temporary name?

Comment: How are you downloading the file?

Answer (score 5):

If the file is still being downloaded, there might be a temporary file with the extension `.part`. Check if that file exists and is still getting bigger as the download proceeds.

Downloading large files using HTTPS might lead to corrupted files, especially with unstable connections.

Another download option would be downloading via torrent. Torrent downloads can be interrupted with connections losses, power outages etc. but it will start to download from where it's left when the interruption is solved. Necessary torrent links can be found in [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)